# indexPath.row-1 is 4294967295

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have an indexPath.row that is 1 and logs 1(when using NSLog). If I call indexPath.row-1 (should return 0) it returns 4294967295.

I'm trying to return an `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1` but that's when I get 4294967295.

Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Singleton *singleton = [Singleton sharedSingleton];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"isYes"]boolValue] == 1 && randomMarker != 100)
    {
        //sets cell image
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,98,100)];
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stackoverflow.png"];
        cell.imageView.image = imgView.image;

        //sets cell text
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Text";
        self.checkedInCount == 100;
    }
    else if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"isYes"]boolValue] == 1 && randomMarker == 100)
    {
        //gets cell and cleans up cell text
        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath.row);
        NSString *title = [[[singleton linkedList]objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)]objectForKey:@"desc"];
```

Comment: My guess is that you're actually trying to get objectAtIndex:-1, which is nonsense. Post the code where this is happening for more specific help.

Comment: NSString *tempDesc = [[[singleton linkedList]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]objectForKey:@"desc"];

Comment: It crashes on this line stating that the index 4294967295 is out of bounds (0,0)

Comment: Please never post code in comments. Please update your question. We'll need to see where this code is placed to determine the actual value of `indexPath.row`.

Comment: What is the log output? `NSLog(@"%@", indexPath.row);`.  Also, you probably want `NSLog(@"%u", indexPath.row);` like PengOne pointed out.

Comment: It outputs "1". I'll change it to %u now. I didn't see that edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you attempt to give an unsigned int (`NSUInteger`) a negative value, it often returns a very large positive value instead.

You are calling

```
NSString *tempDesc = [[[singleton linkedList]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]objectForKey:@"desc"];
```

when `indexPath.row` has value `0`, so the translation is:

```
NSString *tempDesc = [[[singleton linkedList]objectAtIndex:-1]objectForKey:@"desc"];
```

Since `objectAtIndex:` takes an unsigned integer as its parameter, `-1` is converted to a garbage value of `4294967295`.

To avoid this problem, don't subtract `1` from `0` by checking first that `indexPath.row` is positive.

---

Here's another problem:

```
NSLog(@"%@", indexPath.row);
```

This should instead read:

```
NSLog(@"%u", indexPath.row);
```

Comment: indexPath.row does not have a value of 0, it has a value of 1. If I use NSLog to dump the indexPath.row, it logs 1.

Comment: @James, `-tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for **every** valid `indexPath`, beginning with the one with section `0` and row `0`.

Comment: In my actual code, this line is within an if statement that is not called unless indexPath>0. :(

Comment: @James: Post **all** of the relevant code. Otherwise you're wasting my time.

Comment: @James I'm sure it is just the relaxed syntax in your comment but when you say `indexPath>0`, you mean `indexPath.row>0` right? Anyway, post the actual code if you can, you might be leaving something important out.

Comment: @Albert yes. I'll post some more.

Comment: @PengOne +1 for good answer.  Seems likely that NSUInteger is being subtracted and jumping to upper bound (hence large int).  Good catch on log as well.  I think your answer points in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"%@", indexPath.row);
```

You shold use %d for integer as indexPath.row will return an integer

Use
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);